# JUnit5: Running a single "instance" of parameterized test

Tags: maven, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

Let's say we have a parameterized test `exampleTest` in JUnit5:

```
public class ExampleTestClass {

    @ParameterizedTest(name = "exampleTest[{0}]")
    @MethodSource("StringParams#getStrings")
    void exampleTest(String input) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class StringParams {
    static Stream<String> getStrings() {
        return Stream.of("a", "b", "c");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to execute only one instantiation of `exampleTest` in `JUnit5`? In `JUnit4+Maven+Surefire`, the following would work:

```
mvn test -Dtest="ExampleTestClass#exampleTest[a]"
```

But it doesn't seem to work with `JUnit5+Maven+Surefire`. Is it because the test names that get into the test selecting process (which tests will be executed and which are going to be omitted) are different from the one specified in `@ParameterizedTest(name = "exampleTest[{0}])`?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but the doc of [`surefire:test#test`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test) reads:

> **<test>**
>
> [...] Since 2.7.3, you can execute a limited number of methods in the test by adding #myMethod or #my*ethod. For example, -Dtest=MyTest#myMethod. **This is supported for junit 4.x** and TestNg.
>
> Since 2.19 a complex syntax is supported in one parameter (**JUnit 4, JUnit 4.7+**, TestNG):

(Emphases by me.)

Comment: I think this refers to non-parameterized test selectors. I can confirm that these still work in JUnit5, despite not being explicitly listed in the documentation. Sadly, their documentation does not mention anything about parameterized test selector support in JUnit5 - and based on my inability to find anything on this topic, I'm starting to think that this feature is simply not supported.